# Prove $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{x}\int_0^xf(t)dt=a$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits

Let $f:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ continuous and $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x)=a$. Claim: $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{x}\int_0^xf(t)dt=a$.

My try: It is $\int_0^xf(t)dt=F(x)-F(0)$ (because of the fundamentaltheorem of calculus) and $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}F(x)=ax+b$, because $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x)=a$.
What can I do next, or do you have an idea how to prove it? Regards

Comment: Hint: $\frac{1}{x}\int_0^x (f(t)-a)dt=\frac{1}{x}\int_0^x f(t)dt -a$, so it suffices to assume $a=0$

Comment: I'll do one more hint: that value for $F(x)$ is unmotivated. Try working with the definition of $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)=0$ and think of some integral inequalities.

Comment: The basic epsilon-delta method (or rather, epsilon-X) works like a charm here. Did you try it? (Note that $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}F(x)=ax+b$ is an ill-formed identity since there can be no $x$ on the RHS.)

Answer (score 3):

Use L'Hôpital's rule and the fundamental theorem of calculus. There are two cases.

**Case 1**: $\int_0^\infty f(t)dt = \pm \infty$. In this case, by L'Hôpital's rule and the FTC, $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{x} \int_0^x f(t)dt = \lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^x f(t)dt}{\frac{d}{dx}x} = \lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{f(x)}{1} = a \text{.}$$

**Case 2**: $\int_0^\infty f(t)dt$ is finite. Then the limit in question is clearly 0, and we must show that $a = 0$ as well. However, if $a \neq 0$, then $f$ is eventually bounded away from 0, and so the improper integral would be infinite (a contradiction).

Comment: Nice use of the l'Hôpital rule.

Answer (score 1):

Let us go back to the rigorous definition of the limit and it works straightforwardly. 
For any $\epsilon>0$, there is an $X>0$ such that $\forall x>X$, $|f(x)-a|<\epsilon/2$. For such an $x$, let us compute 
$$\begin{split}
\left\lvert-a+\frac1x\int_0^xf(t)\mathrm dt\right\rvert&=\frac1x\left\lvert-aX+\int_0^Xf(t)\mathrm dt+\int_X^x(f(t)-a)\mathrm dt\right\rvert\\&\leq
\frac bx+\frac1x\int_X^x|f(t)-a|\mathrm dt\quad\left(\text{with}\;b=\left|\int_0^Xf(t)\mathrm dt-aX\right|\right)\\
&\leq\frac bx+\frac{x-X}x\frac\epsilon2\\&\leq\frac{b}x+\frac\epsilon2.\end{split}$$ 
For all $x>2\frac b\epsilon$ we have $\frac{b}x<\frac\epsilon2$. Therefore, for all $x>\max\{X,2\frac b\epsilon\}$, $$\left\lvert\frac1x\int_0^xf(t)\mathrm dt-a\right\rvert<\epsilon.$$

Answer (score -1):

You're close: as $\;f\;$ is continuous it has a primitive $\;F\;$ , so

$$\frac1x\int_0^xf(t)dt=\frac{F(x)-F(0)}{x-0}\stackrel{MVT}=F'(c_x)=f(c_x)\;,\;\;c_x\in(0,x)$$

and now just take the limit $\;x\to\infty\;$ ... **and be careful** (for example, for different $\;x$'s one could possibly get *the same* $\;c_x\;$ . How do you go around this?)

Comment: I don't see how this works. There is no reason $c_x$ needs to approach $\infty$ as $x$ does.

Comment: @MikeHaskel I know, and that is why the *be careful*  note **for the OP** .

Comment: "Be careful" means the method works if one is careful. What if the method *cannot work*?

Comment: If the method doesn't work then I'm wrong....not my first or second time. :) Yet I think it can work with care, though somebody already decided it doesn't. Oh, well...

Comment: Then *make it work*... :-) Until then, this is not an answer (and if in the end the approach does not work, the post is misleading).

Comment: Nop. I shall wait until the OP addresses and *thinks* of this instead of  trying to please *other people* who want things that they can understand at once. In the meantime, they can continue to downvote the answer. :) . And answers in this site are **many** times given in form of hints and half ways, as someone with more than  4 years of membership should by now know.

Comment: Assuming this last comment is addressed to me: indeed, reading answers on this site led me to the conclusion that *so-called hints leading nowhere* are a plague. Please be more reasonable.

Comment: @Did Please be less intruding into what *others* consider convenient or not. You're **not** the highest authority on what is a good or bad answer here, and I think you're well aware that many very good members in the site answer by the way of hints. If you want to give complete, detailed answers that's your right. Don't hit others for not doing it that way...and **still** the OP hasn't said about this and other good answers have been posted. *Even* if my method happens to be wrong, the OP (and others...) can learn from it, at least to be *always* careful...as written there.

Comment: Oh, well: look, an upvote...:)

Comment: Congratulations for making sure this exchange will generate no benefit of any kind. Your misconceptions about the site are impressive.

Comment: @Did  I'm truly and sincerely convinced not only my "misconceptions about the site" (??) are the only, or even the main, thing that is *impressive* here.  And I still think this exchange will be positive for some.